# Are you able to mix amber with different elements to give properties beyond encasing and preserving?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, materials

Is it possible to mix it with other elements to give it properties beyond preservation? Like strengthen a sword, or enhance a person's muscles.

I've been looking around to see, however I've yet to come up with anything that reveals the answer to me. If anyone could give a theoretical answer, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to preserve, and how intact it needs to be? Amber fossils frequently preserve bugs millions of years, but they're still dead bugs obviously.

Comment: For example, a thin layer of amber encasing a sword? Mixing the amber into muscle tissue?

Comment: Welcome to WB.SE! I'm not sure what you're actually asking.  It took .33 seconds with google to discover that there are amber fossils [230 million years old](http://www.eartharchives.org/articles/trapped-in-time-the-top-10-amber-fossils/) Until you clarify what you're actually interested in, and also ensure that it has worldbuilding context, I'm voting to close.  Lastly, please take a look at the [help] and [tour] so you can get an idea what we're looking for in questions here.  Also note that at SE, you can only ask one question at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer on how long it took to google. I've misphrased my title and question. What I meant to ask is that if you're you able to mix amber with different things to give it properties beyond encasing and preserving.

Comment: @Dae_MMOn Look up amber on Wikipedia. There’s a section on “uses”. It’s basically jewelry, folk medicine, and perfume. No mention of other applications or combination with other materials. So the answer in the real world is “no”, or “none we know of”. The answer in your fictional world is as large as your imagination.

Comment: I see.  Or rather, I don't see.... I'm still unclear where you're headed with the question!

Comment: If you mix amber dust with air you'll get a decent explosive. Just look up [dust explosions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_explosion). So yes you can mix it with other materials and get properties beyond encasing and preserving. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: You could cover a sword in amber to waterproof it, but that probably falls under encasing or preserving. i believe it's also used as incense, but I may be thinking of something else

Answer (score 3):

Amber is transformed resin by application of heat and time. It's not particularly hard (scores a 2/10 on Mohs, compare to iron which is 4/10), nor is it made from any particularly rare elements. Amber is made from resin, resin is mainly made from turpenes, which can be derived from isoprene formulas (that is, a multiple of C5H8). It's just carbon and hydrogen. It's got similar properties to tar in that sense. You can play around with it to get terpenoids, which contain a few drugs, some odd flavors, and flammable substances. But that's not what you're looking for.

Injecting it into a human isn't a great idea, I'm not even sure how'd you go about doing it, considering that it's a crystallized solid. You can add it to iron and forge it in to get carbon-infused iron which is stronger than normal iron - but that's just what steel is. If you wanted to try something really weird, you can dunk a sword in resin and leave it to crystallized to amber over a few centuries, in which case you will get an odd sword which may have a far stronger surface from the iron-carbon interactions. Or you may not, I have no idea what would happen. (And, for technical reasons, if you're doing that, you want a mace, not a sword.)

Comment: *"Crystallized solid:"* Amber is amorphous. (Like, for example, acrylic glass, plexiglass, and other such organic glasses, which are a sort of artifical amber.)